# How to use django filetransefers api?

Tags: django

I've installed [filetransfers](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers) to mainly use it to upload and download files using django within an app.  I do the file uploads without problems, but I have a problem with the download section.  This is what my upload code:

```
from filetransfers.api import serve_file

class UploadFile(models.Model):
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/')

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = UploadFile
```

... and download code:

```
def download_handler(request, pk):
                upload = get_object_or_404(UploadFile, pk=pk)
                return serve_file(request, upload.file)
```

But it doesn't work:  Is there a way to create a download link or if someone clicks on the uploaded file does it download it immediately?

Comment: Downvoted for: no formatting; no link to whatever "the filetransfers api" is; no explanation of what "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you [configure your backends](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers#id6)?

For private download, did you add a url to your download handler in [urls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)?

The [download link is available in the template as described in the docs](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers#id5):

```
{% load filetransfers %}
{% url upload.views.download_handler pk=upload.pk as fallback_url %}
<a href="{% firstof upload.file|public_download_url fallback_url %}">Download</a>
```